# Relationships in SQLAlchemy are not working as expected

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a relationship between two tables; event and location.
The thing I am trying to accomplish is to create a one to many relationship. A event can be given at a location, so that location must be able to hold various Events. I have been fiddling with foreign keys for hours and I cannot figure out how to get it working.

My location.py looks like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey, Float, Date, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from model import Base

class Location(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'location'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    title = Column(String, unique=True)
    description = Column(String, nullable=False)
    founder_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    latitude = Column(Float)
    longtitude = Column(Float)
    creation_date = Column(Date, default=datetime.now)


    # Relationships
    creator = relationship('User', foreign_keys=founder_id)
    events = relationship('Event', back_populates='location')
```

and the event.py looks like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Date, Float, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from model import Base
from model.event_contestant import EventContestant
from model.location import Location


class Event(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'event'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    date = Column(Date, nullable=False)
    location_id = Column(Integer),
    longtitude = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    latitude = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    description = Column(String, nullable=False)
    difficulty = Column(Integer, nullable=False, default=3)
    creation_date = Column(Date, nullable=False, default=datetime.now)
    event_creator = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    event_type = Column(String, nullable=False, default='Freestyle')

    # Relationships
    creator = relationship("User")
    contestants = relationship(EventContestant, back_populates="event")
    location = relationship('Location', foreign_key=location_id)
```

The stactrace I get from sqlalchemy looks like the following:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'Mapper|Location|location'. Original exception was: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Location.events - there are no foreign keys linking these tables. Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
```

I'm truly puzzled and can't find out why this one to many should just work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Event` needs a `ForeignKey` pointing to `Location` in order to construct the relationship.  Specifically, you want to change the definition of `Event.location_id` to add `ForeignKey('location.id')` (and get rid of that trailing comma; `Event.location_id` is currently a tuple).

Comment: I tried setting location_id as a foreign key tied on Location.id but this didn't see mto work.